# DirectX11 - Geometry Shader with Stream Output

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

I'm trying to stream out data from the geometry shader to use as a vertex buffer to be input into another shader. However, this doesn't seem to be working, and the debug layer is telling me nothing. Is there something I'm doing wrong with the buffer descriptions?

Here's how I'm creating the output buffer:

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC outputBufferDesc;
ZeroMemory(&outputBufferDesc, sizeof(outputBufferDesc));
outputBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(XMFLOAT4) + 2 * sizeof(XMFLOAT3);
outputBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
outputBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_STREAM_OUTPUT;
outputBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
outputBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
outputBufferDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;

result = renderer->CreateBuffer(&outputBufferDesc, NULL, &outputBuffer);
if (result != S_OK)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, filename, L"Failed to create stream output buffer", MB_OK);
    exit(0);
}

UINT offset[1] = { 0 };
deviceContext->SOSetTargets(1, &outputBuffer, offset);
```

And the draw call for the first shader:

```
deviceContext->VSSetShader(vertexShader, NULL, 0);
deviceContext->PSSetShader(pixelShader, NULL, 0);
deviceContext->GSSetShader(streamOutputGeometryShader, NULL, 0);

// Render the triangle.
deviceContext->DrawIndexed(indexCount, 0, 0);

UINT offset[1] = { 0 };
ID3D11Buffer* pNullBuffer = 0;
deviceContext->SOSetTargets(1, &pNullBuffer, offset);
```

And where I copy the information from that buffer into a second buffer:

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc;
ZeroMemory(&vertexBufferDesc, sizeof(vertexBufferDesc));
vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(XMFLOAT4) + 2 * sizeof(XMFLOAT3);
vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
vertexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
vertexBufferDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;

result = renderer->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, NULL, &vertexBuffer);
if (result != S_OK)
{

    MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to create output mesh vertex buffer", L"Failed", MB_OK);
    exit(0);

}

deviceContext->CopyResource(vertexBuffer, buffer);
```

And where I set the input topology for the mesh using the vertex buffer:

```
unsigned int stride;
unsigned int offset;

// Set vertex buffer stride and offset.
stride = sizeof(XMFLOAT4) + 2 * sizeof(XMFLOAT3);
offset = 0;

deviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
```

And finally, the draw call for the second shader is simple:

```
deviceContext->DrawAuto();
```

EDIT: The geometry is being computed in the geometry shader correctly, but it's not being streamed out. I've included the geometry shader creation code below:

```
D3D11_SO_DECLARATION_ENTRY SODeclarationEntry[3] =
{

    { 0, "SV_POSITION", 0, 0, 4, 0 },
    { 0, "NORMAL", 0, 0, 3, 0 },
    { 0, "TEXCOORD", 0, 0, 3, 0 }

};

// Create the geometry shader from the buffer.
result = renderer->CreateGeometryShaderWithStreamOutput(geometryShaderBuffer->GetBufferPointer(), geometryShaderBuffer->GetBufferSize(), SODeclarationEntry, _countof(SODeclarationEntry),
    NULL, 0, D3D11_SO_NO_RASTERIZED_STREAM, NULL, &streamOutputGeometryShader);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to just the actual vertex data, buffers used as targets for the Stream Output Stage maintain some internal state to keep track of how much geometry was written out. `DrawAuto()` relies on this information to know how much geometry to draw. When you copy just the vertex data out of your stream output buffer into a plain `D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER`, this information will be lost.

Relevant quote from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-drawauto):

> DrawAuto only works when drawing with one input buffer bound as an input to the IA stage at slot 0. Applications must create the SO buffer resource with both binding flags, D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER and D3D11_BIND_STREAM_OUTPUT.

I'm not sure if it's supposed to be possible to copy data from one stream output buffer to another and `DrawAuto()` from there. I guess that might work. What you are doing at the moment, however, is definitely not supposed to work according to the documentation. Ideally, you'd just avoid copying the data. If you really must copy the data (for whatever reason), I suggest you nevertheless first try drawing directly from the buffer you streamed into to make sure everything else is set up correctly and only once that works try to copy into another buffer that has both vertex and stream output bind flags set…

Comment: I've fixed this, but after running the shader through Visual Studio's graphics debugger it appears that nothing is being written to the stream output buffer; it remains 40 bytes in size with every element being 0. This is despite the stream output buffer being assigned and the shader outputting geometry. I've edited my post to include the shader creation, in case that might be incorrect.

Comment: Well, one thing that did strike me as a bit odd about your code up there is that your buffers seem tiny. I assumed you had a reason for that. But now that I notice that your strides are the same as the buffer sizes: You are aware of the fact that the `ByteWidth` is supposed to be the size of the entire buffer and not just the size of a single vertex?

Comment: I figured as much given what the documentation does on MSDN; I must've forgotten to change it back to what it was after tinkering with it (that's what I get for programming at 1 in the morning). Right now I'm just setting the byte width to be a very large value that doesn't change because I don't know the number of vertices that will be in the buffer. Is this the best approach for this situation? Or is there a strategy for dynamically sizing the buffer?

Comment: Well, setting it to "a very large value" should be good enough to make it do something (as long as that very large value is not so large that the allocation fails, of course). Obviously, it's not the best approach in general to just blindly allocate some arbitrary, huge amount of memory. In the case of stream output, you should have at least some idea how much geometry your application is going to process and be able to derive some worst-case size that the buffer needs to be!?

Comment: I do know roughly how much data will be output, but sizing the buffer for a worst case scenario seems somewhat inefficient. I was just curious to see if there's a better way of doing it that I hadn't thought of.

Comment: Well, you could look how much geometry you get the first time and then use a smaller buffer next time. D3D11 does not have any built-in feature I'm aware of to dynamically adapt the size of a buffer to how much geometry is streamed into it. So I'm afraid you're on your own to figure out what approach makes the most sense in your application…